# How to use the HTML5 header tag into Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have this simple **HTML 5** page that have to run well also on **Internet Explorer 8**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="<c:url value="resources/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="<c:url value="resources/css/bootstrap.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="<c:url value="resources/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />" rel="stylesheet">



        <title>Login Page</title>

    </head>

    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <img src="resources/img/logo2.png" class="logo">


        <div id="login-box">

            <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                <div class="error">${error}</div>
            </c:if>

            <form class="form-inline" name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
                <input type='text' name='username' class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Nome Utente">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
                <input type='password' name='password' class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
              </div>

              <!--  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button> -->
              <input id="ricorda" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="login" />

              <br>

              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                </label>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    </header>

    <body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>
        <jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>
        <div id="intestazione">
            <h1 align="center">WIFI e PNSD</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="login-box">

            <h3>Accesso al sistema</h3>

        </div>
         <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>

         <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I try to open it into IE8 it don't see the HTML5 tag as the **header** tag.

So I found this solution: http://tatiyants.com/how-to-get-ie8-to-support-html5-tags-and-web-fonts/

that specify to add these lines inside my page to solve the problem:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script>
      document.createElement('header');
      document.createElement('nav');
      document.createElement('section');
      document.createElement('article');
      document.createElement('aside');
      document.createElement('footer');
   </script>
<![endif]-->
```

But where exatly have I to put these lines inside the previous page? And what exactly does these line?

Tnx

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but aren't you missing the doctype declaration <!DOCTYPE html> at the very beginning?

Comment: IE8? In 2015? Seriously?

Comment: @arkascha OP's example looks slightly business-oriented, and many people are still limited to using IE8 by their employer.

Comment: @Pot-Nut Sure, that is obvious. But what I learned over 25 years of being in the business: employers stick with old software simply because it is still supported. If not they would simply switch, no issue there.

Comment: @arkascha Employers also stick with old software because it costs them a fortune (and takes a very long time) for risk/security assessment of the replacement software etc. Upgrading to IE9+ for example is not even possible for employees stuck on Windows XP so this would mean mass OS upgrades for all end users. Luckily XP and IE<8 is beginning to drop off the radar now Microsoft dropped (or rather started charging millions for) support for XP =)

Comment: @Pot-Nut Sorry, I disagree. The behavior you sketch is only to be found in big public institutions, never in small companies and it is extremely rare in big companies. The true reason for not upgrading is 1. Sloth and lazyness, 2. not being responsible in person for security risks and the like, 3. fear of change. The excuse about costs of an upgrade is cheap, if that really were an issue, then people would simply switch to Linux. The simple truth is: it is always easy to push everything to the next day if you are not responsible yourself.

Comment: @arkascha Sorry, my comments were based on past experiences with two large employers, so I agree it is likely limited to that type of institution. I was just presenting the other side of the coin - for all we know OP may work for a large employer and is limited to IE8 for these very reasons. I only hope OP isn't supporting IE8 for the sake of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AndreaNobili, Please add in your html file head :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
 </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Now ie 8 browser support your all html5 elements.

Comment: If you add this html5.js then you don't need any type of script like you add:

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script>
      document.createElement('header');
      document.createElement('nav');
      document.createElement('section');
      document.createElement('article');
      document.createElement('aside');
      document.createElement('footer');
   </script>
<![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 Shiv to add compatibility back to older browsers.

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have used and posted is an [IE conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) and with your example will force any version of IE below 9 to render, and therefore recognise, these elements.

There are a couple of issues with your page though. You are missing the HTML5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>` above your `<html>` tag. You may also need to add `display: block` to the HTML5 elements in your CSS.

You asked where you should use the conditional comment. This can either go inside of your `<head>` section or just above the closing `</body>` tag. To ensure no [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) or any IE quirks I would recommend it was placed inside the `<head>` tags.

Alternatively, the easiest option would be to use [Lalji Tadhani's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32179075/3112083) of the HTML5 shiv.

Comment: TFW when OP asks multiple questions and accepts a one-liner 'stick this script on your page', rather than the reply that actually answers all of their questions... :(